# Metro Bundler Crashing after running react-native run-android

Tags: node.js, react-native, metro-bundler

The metro of my react native app keep crashing when using react-native run-android. Though i have seen some fixes which include updating the blacklist.js file in the metroconfig folder.
My problem is there is no blacklist.js in my metroconfig folder maybe because i am using the latest version of node. How do i edit the exclusion List to make the metro stop crashing please.
Thanks for your help

I tried closing the metro and restarting the server several times but these didn't work. I believe i need to reconfigure the exclusionList.js which was used to replace the blacklist.js but i can't just figure how to do it.
Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of React Native (0.64 onwards), the blacklist function in Metro has been renamed to exclusionList, and the configuration entry blacklistRE has been renamed to blockList. You can use this function to exclude certain directories in your Metro configuration.

Here is how you can update your metro.config.js:

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

// exclusionList is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default exclusions to return a single regex.

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blockList: exclusionList([/dist\/.*/]) // replace '/dist\/.*/' with the regex matching the path you want to exclude
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Please do you know a solution as to why the metro bundler keeps closing thus making the react native app not build.

Comment: On a previous post , the solution was to edit the blacklist.js file but in my case there is not blacklist.js , rather it is exclusionList.js file i have